# Socket Hangup in Node, Express and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sockets, express

I am developing a MEAN stack application. I am requesting to coincap.io APis for getting coin data using cronjobs and request library in Node and Express and after fetching the data I am pushing the data into my MLAB MongoDb instance in the interval of 5 minutes.

I am getting the following errors in the console.

```
{ Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.17.39.95:80
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:999:13)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1020:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1207:14)
  errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '104.17.39.95',
  port: 80 }

{ Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:330:15)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:423:23)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:164:20)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1062:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:152:19) code: 'ECONNRESET' }
```

Below is my mongoose configuration in server.js file.

```
const options = {
    reconnectTries: 10, // Never stop trying to reconnect
    reconnectInterval: 500, // Reconnect every 500msi.e 0.5 sec
    poolSize: 15, // Maintain up to 15 socket connections
    socketTimeoutMS: 0, // Close sockets after 5 minute of inactivity
    connectTimeoutMS: 0,
    family: 4, // Use IPv4, skip trying IPv6
    keepAlive: true
};

// Connect to database via mongoose
mongoose.connect(config.database, options)
  .then(() => console.log(`MongoDB Connected ${config.database}`))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

And Server is set for no timeout using the below code as,

```
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`));
app.listen().setTimeout(0);
```

Below is the funtion for getting the Data provided by the URL.

```
var historyGraphTask = cron.schedule('*/15 * * * *', function () {
    CoinGraph.count(function (err, count) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            CoinGraph.find({}, (err, coinData) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    for (var i = 0; i < coinData.length; i++) {
                        let symbol = coinData[i].symbol;
                        const historyUrl = 'http://coincap.io/history/' + symbol;
                        DataReq(historyUrl).then((data) => {
                            if (data === null || data === undefined) {
                                console.log('Data Error in cron job of graph');
                            } else {
                                const newData = data.Data;
                                HistoryData.findOneAndUpdate({symbol: symbol} , { data : newData  }, { safe: true, upsert: true }  ,(err, historyData) => {
                                    if (err) {
                                        console.log(err);
                                    } else {
                                        CoinGraph.findOneAndUpdate({ symbol: symbol }, { historyData: historyData._id }, { safe: true, upsert: true } , function (err, updatedData) {
                                            if (err) {
                                                console.log(err);
                                            } else {
                                                console.log(updatedData);
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                }); 

                            }
                        }).catch((error) => {
                            console.log(error);
                        });

                    }
                }
            });
        }

    });
});

function DataReq(Url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request(Url, {timeout: 0}, function (error, response, body) {
            if (body === undefined || body === null || error) {
                console.log(error);
                return;
            } else {
                const Data = JSON.parse(body);
                if (Data) {
                    resolve({ Data });
                } else {
                    reject();
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

What I am doing wrong ? I have tried all possible solutions and yet stuck on this from a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, it doesn't look like it is ending. By ending, I mean doing any callbacks to end the function.

My initial finding is that you need to somehow do a callback.

I would suggest you check the documentation for the proper handling of the request either in the CRON library you are using or the coingraph docs.